# Haskell join function inputs in list in specific order

Tags: haskell

[Exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xjnK.png)

Hello every one!

I have been struggling to get this function working in the specific way they want.

I tried everything and the only output I could make was without the starting and ending point, eg: [((a,b),(b,c))]

Could someone please give me some help? I am stucked...

Update: type Point = (Float, Float)

Comment: Could you show what you've tried? That should give us a better idea of exactly what part you're having trouble with.

Comment: please narrow down your problem. How far do you get on your own and where exactly do you need help? We are not starting to just randomly solve everyones homework...

Comment: @Jere I got the hint I needed! The only thing missing was joining first and second input to the beginning and ending respectively. Thanks for the interest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well since you got it working without the starting/ending point. An easy way to complete would be use your function but add the starting/ending point in the list in an inner function. So your interface is still same.

Another way using recursion, pattern matching and guards is:

```
-- assuming the inputs to be int as definition of point not given
solve x z [] = [(x,z)]

solve x z (y:ys)
            | x == 0 = solve y z ys     -- x ==0 to be replaced by null/empty condition on x
            | null ys && z == 0 = []    -- z ==0 to be replaced by null/empty condition on z
            | null ys = [(y, z)]
            | otherwise = (x,y) : solve y z ys
```

Added a base case when the list is empty or start/end points not valid based on darthfennec comment.

Comment: That base case doesn't look quite right. I don't think you should be ignoring `x`.

Comment: I forgot to include, the Point is: type Point = (Float, Float)

I am trying now your solutions and thank you for a quick  reply!!